# Create a Google Map container

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, containers, infowindow

I am using Xamarin and am developing a Google Maps application. I would like to create my own style of the InfoWindow concept.

Is it possible for me to create a "box" that can be used as a container that can be positioned on a Google Map. Inside the "box", I can load a View or display some TextViews that have AutoLink properties that I can click on, rather than the current InfoWindow that is just an image?

Is this possible? Is it easy to do? May I please have some resources and/or advice on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I really dislikes the InfoWindow provided by google.

I found that it is not flexible enough to suit the needs I have for customization.

In my recent google maps project I have been using a third party infowindow called 'infobox'.

You might wanna try it out - its really flexible.

.

You can see some demos here:

https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

The full documentation can be found here:

https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html